# Is it normal that sandbox.paypal.com returns tomcat error HTTP Status 404

Tags: paypal

I am trying for the first time to setup Paypal PDT and want to test it against the sandbox.

When I try to go to http://sandbox.paypal.com, I am getting forwarded to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/hk/webapps/mpp/home , then I get an error generated by Tomcat (404).

Is that normal? Is this site to be used only though APIs and am I doing something wrong when opening it directly in a browser?

Under the FAQ, I can read that

> I'm a non-U.S. developer. How does the site redesign affect me?
>
> The current new REST APIs and PayPal Mobile SDKs are currently
>   targeted for the US market only. We will be rolling out in all
>   geographies over the rest of the year.

Is this a reason for that? Is the sandbox a part of the REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it's broken for me to in the UK. I tried using a US proxy, and it seems that it's broken for everyone, no matter where you are.

Best to just sit it out and wait, although in the meantime I'm going to be using something else. Way to go, PayPal.

Answer (score 2):

I apologize for the inconvenience. We are working to fix this as soon as possible. In the meantime please try using https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/home as a workaround to log in.

Comment: thanks for the update! It's good to see that something is done (even if late)

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to follow up and to let you know that the 404 issue has been resolved.

Comment: So, what was the final verdict? Is this a service down issue?